# Spring data elasticsearch with username and password

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-template

I am using spring data for the `elasticsearch` and using transport client with the below configuration for `elasticsearchtemplate`. I am wondering how we can provide the shield user name and password to the `elasticsearchtemplate`. Can we do that?

```
<elasticsearch:repositories base-package="edu.mayo.registry.fhir.rest.elasticsearch.repository" />

<elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" client-transport-sniff="true" client-transport-ping-timeout="30s" client-transport-nodes-sampler-interval="30s" 
    cluster-nodes="hostname:9300" />

<!-- <elasticsearch:node-client id="client" local="true"/> -->

<bean name="elasticsearchTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="client" ref="client" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch HTTP authentication in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628214/elasticsearch-http-authentication-in-spring)