# Enable Authentication in Elasticsearch with docker environment variable

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am using a Docker image of Elasticsearch v.6.2.4. My problem is that X-Pack is installed, but it is not asking for credentials.

I know that X-Pack is installed as you can see below:

[image: Screenshot of remark that X-Pack is installed.]

Answer (score 9):

Elasticsearch security features that come with Xpack are not for free, there is a trial version for a month and then a paid version.

But according to this [elastic blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free), it is for free starting in versions (6.8.0 and 7.1.0).

I write this answer to activate free Elasticsearch security features with docker-compose.

> Remember that when using the below code, both Kibana and Elasticsearch node are secure with username and password, so rest client that access Elasticsearch must have the credential, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628214/elasticsearch-http-authentication-in-spring/33630449#33630449) will help.

That's my code:

```
version: '3'

services:
  create_certs:
    container_name: create_certs
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.0
    command: >
      bash -c '
        if [[ ! -f ./config/certificates/elastic-certificates.p12 ]]; then
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert -out config/certificates/elastic-certificates.p12 -pass ""
        fi;
        chown -R 1000:0 /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates
      '
    user: "0"
    working_dir: /usr/share/elasticsearch
    volumes: ['certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates']

  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    depends_on: [create_certs]
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.0
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=MyPassword # password for default user: elastic 
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/elastic-certificates.p12
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/elastic-certificates.p12
    volumes: ['esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data', 'certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates']
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    depends_on: [elasticsearch]
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.8.0
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=MyPassword
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"

volumes: {"esdata", "certs"}
```

Answer (score 7):

### Enable Security in Elasticsearch using docker

Update the environment variables t enable true

```
environment:
  - "discovery.type=single-node"
  - ELASTIC_USERNAME=elastic
  - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=MagicWord
  - xpack.security.enabled=true
```

Here is the sample, `docker-compose.yml` file for the elasticseaarch and kibana

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
        - "discovery.type=single-node"
        - ELASTIC_USERNAME=elastic
        - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=MagicWord
        - xpack.security.enabled=true
      ports:
        - 9200:9200
        - 9300:9300
      networks:
        - elastic

    kibana:
      image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.16.2
      container_name: kibana
      environment:
        - ELASTICSEARCH_URL="http://elasticsearch:9200"
        - ELASTIC_USERNAME=elastic
        - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=MagicWord
        - xpack.security.enabled=true
      links:
       - elasticsearch
      ports: 
        - 5601:5601
      networks: 
        - elastic
      depends_on: 
        - elasticsearch  

  networks:
    elastic:
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: Unfortunately something must have changed for version 7. I get `Authentication of [elastic] was terminated by realm [reserved] - failed to authenticate user [elastic]` errors after starting this exact stack.

Comment: It is not the case in this script, but I had the problem of the `failed to authenticate user [elastic]` even by provided the variable. The `ELASTIC_PASSWORD` is used by [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/54eb955a650211cb5d1705f7bacd9d47d2a706dd/distribution/docker/src/docker/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh#L42) so if you overwrite the `command` docker section to start with something else the password could not be set.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I came too late... but I had this problem today and digging found tha you don't have to set the user, just the password. This is the docker-compose file

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  elasticsearchNode:
    image: elasticsearch:$STACK_VERSION
    container_name: elasticsearchNode
    environment:
      discovery.type: 'single-node'
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: $ELK_PASS
      cluster.name: 'dockercluster'
      node.name: 'node-master'
      bootstrap.memory_lock: 'true'
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: '-Xms512m -Xmx512m'
      xpack.security.enabled: 'true'
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - docker_elk_node
volumes:
  esdataNode:
networks:
  docker_elk_node:
```

and the .env file

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=es
STACK_VERSION=7.6.0
ELK_PASS=MyPassWord
```

Answer (score 6):

Change elasticsearch environment to "ELASTIC_USERNAME" and "ELASTIC_PASSWORD" for elasticsearch:7.14.0

```
version: '3.4'
    services:
      elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
        container_name: elasticsearch
        environment:
            - "discovery.type=single-node"
            - ELASTIC_USERNAME=elastic
            - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=MagicWord
            - xpack.security.enabled=true
        ports:
            - 32769:9200
            - 32770:9300
        networks:
            - elastic

      kibana:
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.14.0
        container_name: kibana
        environment:
          - ELASTICSEARCH_URL="http://elasticsearch:9200"
          - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
          - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=MagicWord
          - xpack.security.enabled=true
        links:
         - elasticsearch
        ports: 
          - 5601:5601
        networks: 
          - elastic
        depends_on: 
          - elasticsearch  

    networks:
      elastic:
         driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 3):

Attached is a simple configuration for elasticsearch > 7.x.

Elasticsearch expects the user "**elastic**".

```
  elasticsearch:
  container_name: search
  image: elasticsearch:7.10.1
  restart: always
  ports:
   - 9200:9200
   - 9300:9300
  environment:
   - "discovery.type=single-node"
   - xpack.security.enabled=true
   - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD
```