# how to setup kibana user credentials with docker elk stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-x-pack

How to setup login credentials for kibana gui with docker elk stack containers.

What arguments and environmental variables must be passed in docker-compose.yaml file to get this working.

Comment: Refer to my awnser if you have a problem, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60873733/4042213

Answer (score 5):

For setting kibana user credentials for docker elk stack, we have to set `xpack.security.enabled: true` either in `elasticsearch.yml` or pass this as a environment variable in `docker-compose.yml` file.

Pass username & password as environment variable in `docker-compose.yml` like below:

```yaml
version: '3.3'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    configs:
      - source: elastic_config
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_USERNAME: "elastic"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: "MyPw123"
      http.cors.enabled: "true"
      http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
      xpack.security.enabled: "true"
    networks:
      - elk
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1

  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.6.1
    ports:
      - "5044:5044"
      - "9600:9600"
    configs:
      - source: logstash_config
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:rw
      - source: logstash_pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url: "elasticsearch:9200"
      xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: "elastic"
      xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: "MyPw123"
    networks:
      - elk
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.1
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    configs:
      - source: kibana_config
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    networks:
      - elk
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1

configs:
  elastic_config:
    file: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
  logstash_config:
    file: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
  logstash_pipeline:
    file: ./logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
  kibana_config:
    file: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml

networks:
  elk:
    driver: overlay
```

Then add this following lines to `kibana.yml`:

```yaml
elasticsearch.username: "elastic"
elasticsearch.password: "MyPw123"
```

Comment: Just in case, `elasticsearch.url` became `elasticsearch.hosts` and expects an array of URL

Comment: This will work. Note, however, that this is using the most powerful "elastic" user for all tasks, while there is a sophisticated role concept giving kibana and logstash just the privileges they need.

Comment: Is there any way without using `configs` or custom `Dockerfile`s? (i.e. just using `environment`s)

Answer (score 4):

Did not managed to get it working without adding XPACK_MONITORING & SECURITY flags to kibana's container and there was no need for a config file

However I was not able to use *kibana* user, even after logging in with *elastic* user and changing kibana's password through the UI.

**NOTE**: looks like you can't setup [default built-in users](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html) other than elastic superuser in docker-compose through it's environment. I've tried several times with *kibana* and *kibana_system* to no success.

```
version: "3.7"
services:   
    elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:7.4.0
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 9200:9200
        environment:
            - discovery.type=single-node
            - xpack.security.enabled=true
            - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=123456
    kibana:
        image: kibana:7.4.0
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 5601:5601
        environment:
            - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
            - XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED=true
            - XPACK_MONITORING_COLLECTION_ENABLED=true
            - XPACK_SECURITY_ENABLED=true
            - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
            - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD="123456"
        depends_on:
            - elasticsearch
```

[SOURCE](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/set-password-and-user-with-docker-compose/225075)

**NOTE**: looks like this won't work with 8.5.3, Kibana won't accept superuser *elastic*.

### Update

I was able to setup 8.5.3 but with a couple twists. I would build the whole environment, then in elastic's container run the *setup-passwords auto*

```
bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto
```

[image: elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto command in it's container]

Grab the auto generated password for *kibana_system* user and replace it in *docker-compose* then restart only kibana's container

Kibana 8.5.3 with environment variables:

```
kibana:
    image: kibana:8.5.3
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 5601:5601
    environment:
        - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME="kibana_system"
        - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD="sVUurmsWYEwnliUxp3pX"
```

Restart kibana's container:

```
docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate --no-deps kibana
```

**NOTE**: make sure to use *--no-deps* flag otherwise it will restart elastic container if tagged to kibana's